# tailwindcss not working properly even though all implementation steps are followed?

Tags: tailwind-css, nativewind

After adding tailwind-css according to the instructions of the website https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/expo, unfortunately it does not work during use as seen in the photos.

after typing className, there is no CSS class to add:
[image]

[image]

As you can see in the first photo, after typing className, there is no CSS class to add

Comment: Have you installed [Tailwind intellisense vs code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss)?